# Combine duplicated columns within a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

If I have a dataframe that has columns that include the same name, is there a way to combine the columns that have the same name with some sort of function (i.e. sum)?

For instance with:

```
                NY-WEB01    NY-WEB01
DateTime        
2012-10-18 16:00:00  5.6     2.8
2012-10-18 17:00:00  18.6    12.0
2012-10-18 18:00:00  18.4    12.0
2012-10-18 19:00:00  18.2    12.0
2012-10-18 20:00:00  19.2    12.0
```

How might I collapse the NY-WEB01 columns (there are a  bunch of duplicate columns, not just NY-WEB01) by summing each row where the column name is the same?

Comment: Yes, this is [Split-Apply-Combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) where your aggregating function is `sum()`. This is a very common paradigm. Btw, you're 'aggregating' the rows, not 'merging' them.

Comment: Also, here you're actually combining Rows, not Columns. (You're combining Rows based on certain Columns having the same value (not 'name')). You might like to correct your title.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I believe this does what you are after:

```
df.groupby(lambda x:x, axis=1).sum()
```

Alternatively, between 3% and 15% faster depending on the length of the df:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()
```

EDIT: To extend this beyond sums, use `.agg()` (short for `.aggregate()`):

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(numpy.max)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do for specific columns (with duplicate column names) only?  The reason is that if a column is identified as `Timestamp`, pandas will raise an error `TypeError: Addition/subtraction of integers and integer-arrays with Timestamp is no longer supported.`

Answer (score 20):

### pandas >= 0.20: `df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)`

You don't need a lambda here, nor do you explicitly have to query `df.columns`; [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) accepts a `level` argument you can specify in conjunction with the `axis` argument. This is cleaner, IMO.

```
# Setup
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(50, (5, 5)), columns=list('AABBB'))
df

    A   A   B   B   B
0  44  47   0   3   3
1  39   9  19  21  36
2  23   6  24  24  12
3   1  38  39  23  46
4  24  17  37  25  13
```

<!_ >

```
df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()

    A    B
0  91    6
1  48   76
2  29   60
3  39  108
4  41   75
```

---

## **Handling `MultiIndex` columns**

Another case to consider is when dealing with `MultiIndex` columns. Consider

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one']*3 + ['two']*2, df.columns])
df
  one         two    
    A   A   B   B   B
0  44  47   0   3   3
1  39   9  19  21  36
2  23   6  24  24  12
3   1  38  39  23  46
4  24  17  37  25  13
```

To perform aggregation across the upper levels, use

```
df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).sum()

    A    B
0  91    6
1  48   76
2  29   60
3  39  108
4  41   75
```

or, if aggregating per upper level only, use

```
df.groupby(level=[0, 1], axis=1).sum()

  one     two
    A   B   B
0  91   0   6
1  48  19  57
2  29  24  36
3  39  39  69
4  41  37  38
```

---

## Alternate Interpretation: **Dropping Duplicate Columns**

If you came here looking to find out how to simply drop duplicate columns (without performing any aggregation), use [`Index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html):

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]

    A   B
0  44   0
1  39  19
2  23  24
3   1  39
4  24  37
```

Or, to keep the last ones, specify `keep='last'` (default is `'first'`),

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated(keep='last')]

    A   B
0  47   3
1   9  36
2   6  12
3  38  46
4  17  13
```

The `groupby` alternatives for the two solutions above are  `df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()`, and `... .last()`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Here is possible simplier solution for common aggregation functions like `sum`, `mean`, `median`, `max`, `min`, `std` - only use parameters `axis=1` for working with columns and `level`:

```
#coldspeed samples
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(50, (5, 5)), columns=list('AABBB'))
print (df)

print (df.sum(axis=1, level=0))
    A    B
0  91    6
1  48   76
2  29   60
3  39  108
4  41   75

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one']*3 + ['two']*2, df.columns])

print (df.sum(axis=1, level=1))
    A    B
0  91    6
1  48   76
2  29   60
3  39  108
4  41   75

print (df.sum(axis=1, level=[0,1]))
  one     two
    A   B   B
0  91   0   6
1  48  19  57
2  29  24  36
3  39  39  69
4  41  37  38
```

Similar it working for index, then use `axis=0` instead `axis=1`:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(50, (5, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'), index=list('aabbc'))
print (df)
    A   B   C   D   E
a  44  47   0   3   3
a  39   9  19  21  36
b  23   6  24  24  12
b   1  38  39  23  46
c  24  17  37  25  13

print (df.min(axis=0, level=0))
    A   B   C   D   E
a  39   9   0   3   3
b   1   6  24  23  12
c  24  17  37  25  13

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['bar']*3 + ['foo']*2, df.index])

print (df.mean(axis=0, level=1))
      A     B     C     D     E
a  41.5  28.0   9.5  12.0  19.5
b  12.0  22.0  31.5  23.5  29.0
c  24.0  17.0  37.0  25.0  13.0

print (df.max(axis=0, level=[0,1]))
        A   B   C   D   E
bar a  44  47  19  21  36
    b  23   6  24  24  12
foo b   1  38  39  23  46
    c  24  17  37  25  13
```

If need use another functions like `first`, `last`, `size`, `count` is necessary use [coldspeed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300430/2901002)