# sum vs np.nansum weirdness while summing columns with same name on a pandas dataframe - python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, multiple-columns

taking inspiration from this discussion here on SO ([Merge Columns within a DataFrame that have the Same Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078751/merge-columns-within-a-dataframe-that-have-the-same-name)), I tried the method suggested and, while it works while using the function `sum()` it doesn't when I am using `np.nansum` :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,4), columns=['a', 'a','b','b'], index=pd.date_range('2011-1-1', periods=100))
print(df.head(3))
```

`sum()` case:

```
print(df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(sum, axis=1).head(3))
                   a         b
2011-01-01  1.328933  1.678469
2011-01-02  1.878389  1.343327
2011-01-03  0.964278  1.302857
```

`np.nansum()` case:

```
print(df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(np.nansum, axis=1).head(3))

a    [1.32893299939, 1.87838886222, 0.964278430632,...
b    [1.67846885234, 1.34332662587, 1.30285727348, ...
dtype: object
```

any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `np.nansum` converts its input to a numpy array, so it effectively loses the column information (`sum` doesn't do this).  As a result, the `groupby` doesn't get back any column information when constructing the output, so the output is just a Series of numpy arrays.

Specifically, [the source code for `np.nansum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py#L512) calls the `_replace_nan` function.  In turn, [the source code for `_replace_nan`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py#L60-L62) checks if the input is an array, and converts it to one if it's not.

All hope isn't lost though.  You can easily replicate `np.nansum` with Pandas functions.  Specifically use `sum` followed by `fillna`:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum().fillna(0)
```

The `sum` should ignore `NaN`'s and just sum the non-null values.  The only case you'll get back a `NaN` is if all the values attempting to be summed are `NaN`, which is why `fillna` is required.  Note that you could also do the `fillna` before the `groupby`, i.e. `df.fillna(0).groupby...`.

If you really want to use `np.nansum`, you can recast as `pd.Series`.  This will likely impact performance, as constructing a Series can be a relatively expensive, and you'll be doing it multiple times:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.nansum(x, axis=1), x.index))
```

**Example Computations**

For some example computations, I'll be using the following simple DataFrame, which includes `NaN` values (your example data doesn't):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,2,np.nan,4],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,3,3],[np.nan,np.nan,-1,2,np.nan]], columns=list('aaabb'))

     a    a    a    b    b
0  1.0  2.0  2.0  NaN  4.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0  3.0
2  NaN  NaN -1.0  2.0  NaN
```

Using `sum` without `fillna`:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()

     a    b
0  5.0  4.0
1  NaN  6.0
2 -1.0  2.0
```

Using `sum` and `fillna`:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum().fillna(0)

     a    b
0  5.0  4.0
1  0.0  6.0
2 -1.0  2.0
```

Comparing to the fixed `np.nansum` method:

```
df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.nansum(x, axis=1), x.index))
     a    b
0  5.0  4.0
1  0.0  6.0
2 -1.0  2.0
```