# How do I merge the date column of a concat data frame with N/As

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, merge, concatenation

I have a data frame made by using a blank data frame that I concat multiple data frames onto by looping. Using the following.
`final = pd.concat([final, out], axis=1, sort=True)`
That gave me something similar to

```
Date    Count   Date    Count   Date    Count   Date    Count
1/1/2019    1   1/1/2019    1   N/A N/A 1/1/2019    1
1/2/2019    1   1/2/2019    1   1/2/2019    1   1/2/2019    1
1/3/2019    1   1/3/2019    1   1/3/2019    1   1/3/2019    1
N/A N/A 1/4/2019    1   1/4/2019    1   1/4/2019    1
1/5/2019    1   1/5/2019    1   1/5/2019    1   1/5/2019    1
1/6/2019    1   1/6/2019    1   1/6/2019    1   N/A N/A
N/A N/A 1/7/2019    1   1/7/2019    1   1/7/2019    1
1/8/2019    1   1/8/2019    1   N/A N/A 1/8/2019    1
1/9/2019    1   1/9/2019    1   1/9/2019    1   1/9/2019    1
N/A N/A N/A N/A 1/10/2019   1   1/10/2019   1
1/11/2019   1   1/11/2019   1   1/11/2019   1   1/11/2019   1
1/12/2019   1   1/12/2019   1   1/12/2019   1   1/12/2019   1
1/13/2019   1   1/13/2019   1   1/13/2019   1   N/A N/A
```

However my goal is to get this

```
Date    Count   Count   Count   Count
1/1/2019    1   1   N/A 1
1/2/2019    1   1   1   1
1/3/2019    1   1   1   1
1/4/2019    N/A 1   1   1
1/5/2019    1   1   1   1
1/6/2019    1   1   1   N/A
1/7/2019    N/A 1   1   1
1/8/2019    1   1   N/A 1
1/9/2019    1   1   1   1
1/10/2019   N/A N/A 1   1
1/11/2019   1   1   1   1
1/12/2019   1   1   1   1
1/13/2019   1   1   1   N/A
```

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078751/combine-duplicated-columns-within-a-dataframe/54300430#54300430 You can use `df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).max()`.

Comment: `pd.concat([df[['Date']].ffill().iloc[:,-1],df[['Count']]],1)` and please not using duplicate names in `DataFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you want to combine your `Date` columns together so there are no missing values in the first `Date` column.

Here is the input data

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
         Date  Count     Date.1  Count.1     Date.2  Count.2     Date.3  Count.3
0    1/1/2019    1.0   1/1/2019      1.0        NaN      NaN   1/1/2019      1.0
1    1/2/2019    1.0   1/2/2019      1.0   1/2/2019      1.0   1/2/2019      1.0
2    1/3/2019    1.0   1/3/2019      1.0   1/3/2019      1.0   1/3/2019      1.0
3         NaN    NaN   1/4/2019      1.0   1/4/2019      1.0   1/4/2019      1.0
4    1/5/2019    1.0   1/5/2019      1.0   1/5/2019      1.0   1/5/2019      1.0
5    1/6/2019    1.0   1/6/2019      1.0   1/6/2019      1.0        NaN      NaN
6         NaN    NaN   1/7/2019      1.0   1/7/2019      1.0   1/7/2019      1.0
7    1/8/2019    1.0   1/8/2019      1.0        NaN      NaN   1/8/2019      1.0
8    1/9/2019    1.0   1/9/2019      1.0   1/9/2019      1.0   1/9/2019      1.0
9         NaN    NaN        NaN      NaN  1/10/2019      1.0  1/10/2019      1.0
10  1/11/2019    1.0  1/11/2019      1.0  1/11/2019      1.0  1/11/2019      1.0
11  1/12/2019    1.0  1/12/2019      1.0  1/12/2019      1.0  1/12/2019      1.0
12  1/13/2019    1.0  1/13/2019      1.0  1/13/2019      1.0        NaN      NaN
```

And one possible approach is to then fill the `Date` column `NaN`s with the other `Date` columns one at a time (in this approach, `Date.3` does not appear to be needed)

```
df['Date'].fillna(df['Date.1'], inplace=True)
df['Date'].fillna(df['Date.2'], inplace=True)
df = df.drop(['Date.1','Date.2','Date.3'], axis=1)
```

Output

```
print(df)
         Date  Count  Count.1  Count.2  Count.3
0    1/1/2019    1.0      1.0      NaN      1.0
1    1/2/2019    1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
2    1/3/2019    1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
3    1/4/2019    NaN      1.0      1.0      1.0
4    1/5/2019    1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
5    1/6/2019    1.0      1.0      1.0      NaN
6    1/7/2019    NaN      1.0      1.0      1.0
7    1/8/2019    1.0      1.0      NaN      1.0
8    1/9/2019    1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
9   1/10/2019    NaN      NaN      1.0      1.0
10  1/11/2019    1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
11  1/12/2019    1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
12  1/13/2019    1.0      1.0      1.0      NaN
```

Comment: Sorry to everyone for the delay in marking the answer.
This is probably not the best approach, but it is the most simple way to solve my problem! Without changing how the rest of my script works.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `concat` when you want to be using merge. I'm assuming that out has the data with some values that are going to be missing. Each round of concatenation should be:

```
 final = final.merge(out, on='Date', how='outer')
```

You also might want to use `suffixes` that make sense for your data for example. `suffixes=['','new_data']` in the merge (E.x. `final = final.merge(out, on='Date', how='outer',suffixes=['','new_data'])`. That will help you understand what data came from where

Comment: This would be the correct answer if I had not already used a loop to concat each individual piece one at a time. If I was to redo my thinking this would have been the correct approach. I'd mark it but I don't have enough reputation.